# Registered OCX file cannot be imported in vb 6

Tags: vb6, activex, ocx

I'm trying to import a ocx file into a project... which is in vb6.  I installed it on my x64 Windows 7 machine and so far so good.

Now I'm trying to import an OCX file in this project.  The library was developed by a former employee.

So, I started by registering the file with the 32bits regsvr32 in SysWOW64, where the ocx file is located.

Now, when I try to import it in vb6, here is what I have.  I'm trying to figure this one out:

[image: Error message]

I've edited out the library name, as it is not revelant anyway.

Comment: Also, the messagebox says "Impossible to load".  Sorry, only had a CD with vb in french on it.

Comment: You can use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see VB6 accessing the registry and failing to read a key.  Like the type library for the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [evaluation EditTLB](http://www.powervb.com/edittlbeval.htm), open the ocx and check the external dependencies for missing ones.

Comment: Using EditTLB and SysInternal's Processes Monitor, I was able to find a missing library (vb5 dll, although the project is using vb6).  Now I'm stuck on a missing license, but at least it loads now !